# Group and make row become header

Tags: mysql

I have this data in my MySQL table `fact`

```
+------------+-------+--------+
| timestamp  | code  | unique |
+------------+-------+--------+
| 1416157200 | 7E001 |    100 |
| 1416157200 | 7E002 |    200 |
| 1416243600 | 7E001 |    100 |
| 1416243600 | 7E002 |    200 |
+------------+-------+--------+
```

I want to get this result

```
+-------+------------+------------+
| code  | 2014-11-18 | 2014-11-17 |
+-------+------------+------------+
| 7E001 |        100 |        100 |
| 7E002 |        200 |        200 |
+-------+------------+------------+
```

I use this query `select code, from_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') as date, unique from fact;` to produce this result and have no idea to aggregate this result became above desirable result.

```
+-------+------------+--------+
| code  |    date    | unique |
+-------+------------+--------+
| 7E001 | 2014-11-17 |    100 |
| 7E002 | 2014-11-17 |    200 |
| 7E001 | 2014-11-18 |    100 |
| 7E002 | 2014-11-18 |    200 |
+-------+------------+--------+
```

Is it possible? And how to achieve that?
PS: Please help me editing the title to be more descriptive since I can't explain this problem in such short

Answer (score 0):

Case based aggregation can be used

As the dates can be many, you need to use dynamic SQL

```
  select code, 
      Max( case when  date=1416157200 then unique end) as '2014-11-17' ,
      Max( case when date=1416243600  t hen unique end) as '2014-11-18'
  from fact
  Group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible creating a dynamic query using that values as columns.
I use some code from article describing a way to get a [pivot table in MySQL](http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2014/an-approach-to-mysql-dynamic-cross-reference-query/):

```
mysql> call get_fact_pivot_table();
+-------+------------+------------+
| code  | 2014-11-16 | 2014-11-17 |
+-------+------------+------------+
| 7E001 |        100 |        100 |
| 7E002 |        200 |        200 |
+-------+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0,06 sec)
```

The procedure `get_fact_pivot_table` contains a cursor to make a dynamic query, you can change it as you need:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE if exists get_fact_pivot_table$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `get_fact_pivot_table`()
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE p_sql text;
DECLARE p_col_date VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE p_col_value int;

DECLARE c_columns cursor FOR
    select distinct from_unixtime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') as `col_date` , 
        `timestamp` as col_value
    from fact;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

SET p_sql = 'select f.code ';
OPEN c_columns;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH c_columns INTO p_col_date, p_col_value;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    SET p_sql = concat(p_sql,
      ', (select c.`unique` from fact as c where 
      c.`timestamp` =  ', p_col_value ,' 
      and c.code = f.code limit 1) as `',p_col_date,'` ');

END LOOP;

SET @SQL = concat(p_sql,' from fact as f group by f.code');


close c_columns;

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 


END$$
delimiter ;
```